# sql get value from same table and column queried

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get the value of a column where the query looks up the same column on one table after searching a table before it with a different search field - but it comes up blank. Is this the correct way to go about it?

Example Data:

```
cmsPropertyData
propertytypeid | dataNvarchar
-----------
1 | orange
2 | apple
3 | pear

cmsPropertyType
id | Alias
-------
1 | blue
2 | green
3 | red

cmsContent
nodeId
--------
1
2
3

cmsContentType
id | alias
----------------
1 | holiday
2 | flight
3 | carhire


SELECT pd.dataNvarchar
FROM [cmsPropertyData] pd

INNER JOIN [cmsPropertyType] pt
    ON pt.id = pd.propertytypeid
INNER JOIN [cmsContent] c
    ON c.nodeId = pd.contentNodeId
INNER JOIN [cmsContentType] ct
    ON ct.nodeId = c.contentType

INNER JOIN [cmsPropertyType] z ON pd.id = z.id

WHERE ct.alias = 'holiday'
AND
pt.Alias = 'blue'
AND
pd.dataNvarchar = 'orange'
AND
z.Alias = 'green'
```

So with the example data, I am trying to retrieve 'apple' (pd.dataNvarchar) from cmsPropertyData

Comment: Help us help you - please share you tables' structures, some sample data, and the result you're trying to get for this sample

Comment: You join with the propertyType table twice, once on pd.propertyTypeId which makes sense, but then on pd.id which does not make intuitive sense. Secondly, it is not clear whether you only want to search the 3rd table if the 2nd comes up blank, or you want to search all three but the query comes up blank.

Comment: It kinda-sorts looks like you're attempting to show a hierarchy based on an adjacency list (child/parent & manager/employee, multi-node relationships)... It's not difficult but you'll  need to post sample data if you want help specific to your data, or you can find plenty of examples on the interwebs...Here's a good place to start... https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/performance/the-performance-of-traversing-a-sql-hierarchy/